# How to pass filepath as command line arugement in argparse python

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I need to pass like

```
 Python test.py -H host -U usr -P pass -L c:\newfolder\sample.sh -R /shell/sample.sh
```

I got error message `too many values to unpack`

Please help me to achieve this.

```
def check_argv(args=None)
    parser = argparse.argumentParser()
    parser.add_arugument('-H' , 'host')
    #Same for all argument
#---------------------------------


Host, pass, user , local , remote = check_arg(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Hello there, you need to put in more information, instead of saying "#Same for all argument" you should put all the arguments because there might be a problem with one of the values you passed to your parser.

Comment: Please post the full code for `check_argv()`.

Comment: If that's all there is to your `check_argv`, then it returns `None`, which clearly doesn't match the 5 variables the calling statement expects.  You need in one way or other to call `parse_args` and `return` the five values.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting the error because you are collecting **less** values than your function tuple is returning.That is in line.

And the correct way to use argparser function:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-H', action="store", dest="host")
parser.add_argument('-U', action="store", dest="usr")

params = parser.parse_args()
```

And in your code you can get your parameters like this

```
# FETCHING ARGUMENT DETAILS
print(params.host, params.usr)
```

OUTPUT:

```
$python test.py -H hostname -U testuser   
>>>hostname testuser
```

You can continue adding as many values as needed and get them back in the same way.

Comment: My problem is not to print or how to get that values ..while pass arugement it throws error

Comment: You're getting the error because you are collecting more values than your function tuple is returning.

Comment: @VineethSai you should only keep the second part of your answer, which is the correct way to use `argparse`. Until the OP posts the full code for his `check_arrg()` function anything else is mistly wild guess and won't add much anyway.

Comment: Okay @brunodesthuilliers